# Returning a single value from a filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to return a single value from a filter that returns a large object.

```
return data.filter(subject => subject.id === 1)
   .map((subject) => {
   return subject.total.toString();
    });
```

I have tried, toString, JSON.parse and a few more but always get it either as a single array value.

[112]

or a string inside the array

["112"]

but not a single returned value

112

Is map the wrong method? How do I return a pure integer or string would do?

Comment: The docs of `filter` function says that its return type is `array` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pick the first element. This should suffice..

```
return data.filter(subject => subject.id === 1)[0].total+""
```

Comment: `find` is also more performant, because it stops as soon as it finds a match. Filter will continue and process the whole array anyway.

Answer (score 44):

Instead of `filter` which returns an array with filtered values, use `find`:

```
const subject = data.find(subject => subject.id === 1);
return subject.total.toString();
```

or shorter:

```
return data.find(subject => subject.id === 1).total.toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
return data
   .filter(subject => subject.id === 1)
   .map(subject => subject.total.toString())[0] // Take the first element of the array :)
```

`Array.map` returns an array. If your initial array contains one element, the output array will also contain one element. Just extract it with `[0]`.

Alternatively. `find()` returns one object :

```
return data.find(subject => subject.id === 1).total.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter will always return a array to get the first element use `pop`

```
return data.filter(subject => subject.id === 1)
   .map((subject) => {
   return subject.total;
    }).pop();
```